# merge more than one P with one style

Tags: css, html

```
<div class='comment'>
<div id='image'>image</div>
<div id='date'>date</div>
<p> Comment 1</p>
<p> Comment 2</p>
<p> Comment 3</p>
<div>signature</div>
</div>
```

I need to give all p element one style
for example if i try this :

```
.comment p {
background-color: #CED7BA;
color: rgb(15, 8, 119);
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 10px;
width: 80%;
}
```

it will apply the above style to each P , but i need all P(s) have one border , **keep in mind that i have no control for HTML** , i have permission to write CSS only , how can i give all P(s) one border

Comment: your html is no valid. Also can't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve?

Comment: @alexchar , look , i need to give all P tags one border .

Comment: Where your first DIV with class = "comment" ends?

Comment: What do you mean by one border ?

Comment: @alexchar , if i do so , it will make 3 borders for each p 
i need 3 P placed in one box

Comment: @akshay ,  i need 3 P tags  placed in one box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) and [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) selectors to apply special styling to the first and last paragraph, and then a simple selector for all the paragraphs in between.

Note that this only works as long as the HTML matches exactly what you've posted.

Also keep in mind that these selectors are not supported by IE8.

If the content is any more complex than what you've posted, or you need IE8 support, then you can't do this with CSS alone. You'll need to use javascript, or get permission to modify the HTML.

```css
.comment p:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


.comment p {
    background-color: #CED7BA;
    color: rgb(15, 8, 119);
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 80%;
}


.comment p:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='comment'>
<div id='image'>image</div>
<div id='date'>date</div>
<p> Comment 1</p>
<p> Comment 2</p>
<p> Comment 3</p>
<div>signature</div>
</div>
```

Comment: one more question please , what if i have 1 p in the same case , i mean i don't know how many p will generated , so for more than 1 p , it works , but if i have only one P , it considered as last element and not worked as expected

Answer (score 2):

```css
.comment p {
background-color: #CED7BA;
color: rgb(15, 8, 119);
padding: 10px;
width: 80%;
margin: 0;
}
.comment p:first-of-type{
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
.comment p:last-of-type{
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='comment'>
<div id='image'>image</div>
<div id='date'>date</div>
<p> Comment 1</p>
<p> Comment 2</p>
<p> Comment 3</p>
<div>signature</div>
</div>
```